# When I auto-load a class/file with composer, what is actually happening behind the scenes?

Tags: php, composer-php

I haven't been able to find a strait answer to this question yet elsewhere online and was wondering how exactly composer autoloading worked.

When I autoload a class using PSR-0 or classmap what is actually happening behind the scenes? Is it just calling include(or some include variant) on the the specified file in the specified path. Is it actually skimming the file for class definitions and constructing its own file to include? Is it doing something that isn't analogous to a file include?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A PSR-0 autoloader is simply a function attached to the global PHP process with `spl_autoload_register()`. That registered function is called whenever PHP needs to instantiate a class that isn't yet known, so this is the last moment to make the classes code known before PHP fails.

And the implementation of that autoloading can be either pretty sophisticated, or pretty simple, but in every case it will use either `include()` or `require()` (possibly with `_once`, but this is not really needed) to make the class code known to PHP. You could also implement a call to `eval()` to dynamically add some code that declares the class needed, but this would just be for academic used - I haven't seen it being used in real cases.

The same applies to the classmap loading. The classmap array contains names of classes as keys, and the filename of the containing file as value. This is for cases where there is no PSR-0-compatible ruleset mapping between class name and file path.

If you want more details of how Composer does the autoloading, you should have a look at the generated files inside `vendor/composer`. Basic knowledge about how PHP autoloading works in general would help understand what happens there.

Comment: Ok. This is a perfect explanation. So php goes to check to see if the class is already defined in the current script. If not then it checks to see if it exists in the autoloader. Would you recommend reading up on php autoload itself first or would trying to learn php autoloading from reading the composer source code/generated files be a better way to learn?

Comment: You should read up on PHP autoloading first. Composer then has a working example to examine.

Comment: Thanks Sven. Am checking it out now.

Answer (score 1):

Behind the scenes composer use [spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) to register an autoloader function which include your class.

The registered function follows a standardized namespace/path resolution algorithm (basically consider all "\" or "_" in your class name as path separators from a specified base directory) to find the php file to include.

Also, when you run `composer install` it create a cached index of relation between paths and namespace to speed up the path resolution.

You can dig in the [Github repository](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassLoader.php) and see it for yourself.

Comment: Ok. That makes a lot more sense. I was just starting to see this by looking at the autoload_namespaces.php and autoload_classmap.php files that composer was generating, but I still was pretty confused as to what it was actually doing.

So if I understand correctly. Inside php somewhere there is an autoload stack that is used to store the definitions for classes and functions, and composer just makes it easier/more organized to actually use this feature.

Another question then. What dictates which files actually have these functions autoloaded?

Comment: When you use a class definition inside your script, php try to load that class. If the class definition is not present, before throwing an error, php try to autoload the class calling all functions you manually registered by spl_autoload_register or by the __autoload function. Composer build a standardized stack, but you can create your own. No stack is available in php by default. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php